# How to view the last SMS from the device in the topic with broker Mosquitto?

Tags: python, mqtt, mosquitto

For example, there I am listening to the settings / # topic. The device sends a line to the settings / topicN topic, where N is the device number.

The moment I receive something from the device, I want to see the previous SMS from it.

How to see the moment of receiving data from the device exactly according to

Is this thread just the latest post in python?

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

# The callback for when the client receives a CONNACK response from the server.
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))

    # Subscribing in on_connect() means that if we lose the connection and
    # reconnect then subscriptions will be renewed.
    client.subscribe("settings/#")


# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))
    imei = msg.topic.split('settings/')[1]
    data = msg.payload.decode()
    print(imei)
    print(data)
    publish(client, imei)
    

def publish(client,imei):
    topic = 'test/'+ imei
    client.publish(topic,'hello')
    print('SEND')
    

client = mqtt.Client()
user = 'test'
passw = '1111'
client.username_pw_set(user,passw)
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.enable_bridge_mode()
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70665149/edit) the question and add a lot more detail. Also please read the doc about what a good question should container https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm sorry that really doesn't help. You need to add a lot more context to the explanation, as it is the code doesn't help either.

Comment: @hardillb Is it possible to view the message history using the library paho by topic name? and specifically the last message in this topic

Answer (score 2):

You don't.

If you are not subscribed to a topic then there is no way to see any old messages sent to that topic before you subscribed to it. (With the exception of if the message was published with the retained bit set to true, then the last message published will be delivered by the broker at the point of subscription before any new messages)

If you want to keep the history, then you need to create a client that is always subscribed to the topics and stores them in some sort of database.

Comment: If I am subscribed to a topic, how can I view the story?

Comment: It's up to you to store any incoming messages if you need them later, but code you have shown is only ever subscribed to the `settings/#` topic pattern

Comment: that is, I can only watch history if I subscribe to settings/topicN?

Comment: No, the wildcard topic will see all messages that match, but it's up to you to store any history you want. As I've said your question needs a LOT more context.

Comment: in the on_message function I get the message and topic name. can i call some function, for example show_history (topic_name)??I don’t understand how else to explain to you. at the moment when something comes to the topic, I need to look at old messages and analyze whether there are changes or not

Comment: As I've said, nothing will store the history for you, it is your responsibility to store any messages you may want to use later.